# WKWebView not triggered event when click on upload document button into web

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I have tried this function in Webkit but not getting the event when user clicks on upload document button in web. Any one help me on this.

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt prompt: String, defaultText: String?, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: prompt, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

```
let takePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default) { (action) in
    // Present the camera view controller to take a photo
    // Once the photo is taken, call the completion handler with the file path of the photo
    let imagePath = "file:///path/to/photo.jpg"
    completionHandler(imagePath)
}

let choosePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: .default) { (action) in
    // Present the photo library view controller to select a photo
    // Once the photo is selected, call the completion handler with the file path of the photo
    let imagePath = "file:///path/to/photo.jpg"
    completionHandler(imagePath)
}

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
    completionHandler(nil)
}

alertController.addAction(takePhotoAction)
alertController.addAction(choosePhotoAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}